# Nginx redirect: folder to external domain

Tags: nginx, redirect

I'm trying to redirect domain1.com/blog/$ to domain2.com/$.
How do I edit this to strip the /blog from the redirect?

```
location /blog {
    rewrite ^/(.*) http://domain2.com/$1 break;
}
```

It now redirects domain1.com/blog/blabla to domain2.com/blog/blabla (so blog is still there)..
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You may try: `rewrite ^/blog/(.*) http://domain2.com/$1 break;` (in which case, you might also be able to get rid of the location block).

Comment: It works!!! :) Thanks!!
I can't set your reply as the right one because you added a comment instead of a reply (I think.. I'm rather new here).. :(

Comment: You cannot accept a comment - and respondents shouldn't post answers as comments - it's a bad habit of mine (usually when I don't have a chance to verify my answer). Posted as an answer so you can close out the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the regex part of your rewrite to match against `^/blog/` and capture everything following it:

```
rewrite ^/blog/(.*) http://domain2.com/$1 break;
```

Using such an approach, you may also be able to get rid of the location block.